# Can't get access elements with querySelector?

Tags: javascript

I wish to access elements in a site with javascript and I have been using javascript for quite some time, especially with the `querySelector` functions. But for some reason, it won't work in this case; whenever I try to access any of the top-level elements, as illustrated below, no elements are found.
[image]
Does anyone have an idea about what the problem could be, and maybe even how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal,
It's because when you use the chrome developer console you can change the document context and in your screen you are inside the iframe.

You can see it here:

[image]